# Pass down immutable list to a componenet requiring an Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm new to react and from what I've been reading it's not advised to use .toJS() from as it will affect performance.

But I'm using a third party component that requires an array as props but my state is set as an immutable list.

In this particular case should I use .toJS on my immutable list or do there is another way that wouldn't affect performance ?

Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at seamless-immutable: https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable

Comment: immutablejs List has `toArray` API. It converts to plain array and you can pass the copy to the library. This makes the converted object as a new array which does not modify the original immutable list.

Comment: spend some time in the immutable docs. I find there's usually a method for everything I might want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutable collections have `toArray` method, which will convert any Immutable structure to array. Keep in mind, this operation converts to array only shallowly.